# What board game is this with octagonal Chinese pieces sitting on grid intersections?

Tags: identify-this-game

Will anyone tell me what kind of game this is [image]

Comment: For future reference: if you have a image, you can [Google to find its source](https://lens.google.com/search?p=AU55jv2lE_ifaU2U6tvgrKoT5nMetwn-MggAIriBWtRlRtzNeyo7UrXfuaa0c2MhumMWtFU_Y0sheYCuggtDkDFaY1zMnWJtSwgE3BRfALy_ofWphVEgQPTwn8UXBLbjiVlUo9gpDSps0E5UwfNnbKUQF6xxe2Q3cZ1bkSxVpj3zuoh7KydfBwB7NK6vNiK9PPKW6Vqn2LNT9YTs1zHJJnX7FDy-lb02sCvl4pUQGM-HNMAi7nvVr3-X7w%3D%3D&ep=gisbubu&hl=en-GB#lns=W251bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsIkVrY0tKR1ptTVdRek5UTXdMVGMyWmprdE5EQTJOQzFpWmpNNExUQXpaV0k0TUdReE5qVTNaUklmWnpkUGEwNUdNa056ZDBGUlJVWkRjWGQ0VEhKTVVEZGhOV3hPV2xCU1p3PT0iXQ==)

Answer (score 9):

This is [Janggi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janggi) or "Korean chess". It can be distinguished from [Xiangqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi) ("Chinese chess") by the lack of river dividing the board horizontally in the middle.

Comment: Also can be distinguished for Xiangqi because: the pieces are octagonal, the pieces vary in size, the king starts in the middle of the palace, and the characters on many of the pieces are different

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a form of [Xiangqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi), a relative of shogi and chess.

Comment: Not quite - the lack of river across the middle of board means it's the Korean variant; see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that, it's interesting to see what distinguishes all the East Asian chess-likes.